# How to disable Mouse in Selenium for the Whole page

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have to script some complicated Page 
the Page is like if i want to click one link
for that I need to  mouse over on some text then only that Particular Link will get display then only i can able to click on that link.

we are using one existing framework that has Mouse hover and click function

So for this i am using the Mouse over and webelement click function .

But due to some other mouse interaction the mouse over is not focused to that item text'

So I need to know how to disable mouse in selenium..
Please advise and give me the two functions to deactivate the mouse interaction for the complete run and how to release the deactivation..

Is that possible..?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

use java script click to click on that link forcefully.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
                        "arguments[0].click();",webElement);
```